# Gauss-Newton vs gradient descent vs Levenberg-Marquadt for least squared method

Tags: st.statistics, linear-regression, least-squares

I need to clarify some idea I have in my mind about linear and non-linear regressions. Whatever I know about this topic comes from the book of Taylor "Introduction to error analysis": a set of measurements ${x_i}$ and ${y_i}$ for $i= 1, 2, \dots N$ are assumed to have a trend according to a specific function $y = f(x)$, the discrepancies between the measured value $y_i$ and the function $f(x_i)$ are assumed to follow a Gaussian statistics with variance $\sigma_{y}^2$. Applying the principle of maximum likelihood, the best estimation of the parameters that define $f(x)$ are that ones that minimizes the function.

$$
\chi^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \frac{(y_i - f(x_i))^2}{\sigma_y^2}
$$

This is known as least squared method.

Now in the case of a straight line $f(x) = Ax + B$ the estimation of the parameters is a straightforward job: from a couple of derivatives you figure out $A$ and $B$ and you properly identify $f(x)$. In the more general case $f(x)$ is a polynomial of order $M$, the computation will be more elaborated, but the job is easy at least in principle. In both Matlab and Python there is an implemented function ( polyfit(x, y, M) and np.polyfit(x, y, M) ) that seems to be not difficult to theoretically understand and practically apply to experimental data.

However when the function $f(x)$ is not a polynomial then more complicated numerical methods are necessary in order to figure out the parameters that define $f(x)$. From some google researches I realized that the most popular techniques are

1. **Gauss-Newton algorithm**
2. **Gradient descent algorithm**
3. **Levenberg-Marquadt algorithm**

Matlab and Python have an implemented function called "curve_fit()", from my understanding it is based on the latter algorithm and a "seed" will be the basis of a numerical loop that will provide the parameter estimation.

I would like to know in which case it is better to use the **first** algorithm, in which case the **second** algorithm is better and in which case the **third** one is better.

I would be happy if you suggest me any book or other types of material that provide me a (not too) short explanation of those techniques so that each time I have to fit a curve I can understand which is the better method for me.

Finally I would like to know what you would do if you need to provide a Gaussian fit on a set of experimental data. Personally I did a polyfit of second order of the logarithm of the experimental data. I saw on many Matlab and Python webpages that people uses that "curve_fit" that is, from my understanding, the Levenberg-Marquadt method. Which is the best way to perform these fit from your point of view?

Comment: I think this question should be posted on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also the community at scicomp.stackexchange may have good advice.

Comment: Remark: np.polyfit uses SVD

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Levenberg-Marquardt method is the most effective optimization algorithm, to be preferred over the methods of steepest descent and Gauss-Newton in a wide variety of problems. You might find this [explanation](https://people.duke.edu/~hpgavin/ce281/lm.pdf) by Henri Gavin instructive:

> The Levenberg-Marquardt curve-fitting method is actually a combination
> of the two other minimization methods: the gradient descent method and
> the Gauss-Newton method. In the gradient descent method, the sum of
> the squared errors is reduced by updating the parameters in the
> steepest-descent direction. In the Gauss-Newton method, the sum of the
> squared errors is reduced by assuming the least squares function is
> locally quadratic, and finding the minimum of the quadratic. The
> Levenberg-Marquardt method acts more like a gradient-descent method
> when the parameters are far from their optimal value, and acts more
> like the Gauss-Newton method when the parameters are close to their
> optimal value.

The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm may fail to converge if it begins far from a minimum. There exist ways to accelerate the convergence, as explained [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5885)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm may fail to converge if it begins far from a minimum"? Does this mean it may not converge even in cases where steepest-descent does converge?

Comment: Remark: the issue with Levenberg-Marquardt method is that it's expensive $O(n^{3})$